# Balancing real numbers in one dimension

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry

Given numbers $0 \leq d_i \leq 1$ for $i=1,\ldots,m$, it is easy to see that you can always find signs $\varepsilon_i \in \{-1,1\}$ such that the partial sums $\sum_{i=1}^k \varepsilon_i d_i/2$, for $k=0,\ldots,m$(where $\sum_{i=1}^0 = 0$) lie in an interval of size at most 1. Is this best possible? i.e. is there a choice of $m$ and $d_i$ such that for any choice of signs the strip must be of size at least 1-$\delta$?

Such an example for $\delta = 1/4$ is to take $m = 3$, $d_1 = 1 = d_3$ and $d_2 = 1/2$. What about for smaller $\delta$?

Comment: How can one see that for $\: m = 1 \:$ and $\: d_1 = -3 \;$? $\;\;\;\;$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course, this is best possible. Choose $d_{2k-1}=1$, $d_{2k}=1-\delta$ for $k=1,2,\dots$. If two consecutive signs are the same, we already have two partial sums on a distance $(2-\delta)/2$. If signs alternate, partial sums tend to infinity (actually, we need $m=O(1/\delta)$ for getting too large partial sum).

Comment: I came up with a similar (counter)example for a related problem, but didn't realize you could also apply it here. Is it possible that these are the 'only' bad examples? It is not obvious to me what 'only' should mean, so I understand this question is not very clear.

Comment: In which sense the only? We may add any set of $d$'s in any place, for example